# Flex footer does not move with dropdown menu

Tags: css, flexbox, semantic-ui

I'm having an issue with a dropdown menu expanding the page with a scrollbar, but the footer at the bottom of the page does not move down.

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fmoctax3/

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  background: orange;
}

.ui.dropdown {
  margin-left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class="main">
  <div class="ui floating dropdown">
    <label class="ui button">Dropdown</label>
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  stuff<br>stuff<br>
</div>
```

Why is this happening and how do I get the footer and main to expand as well?

Comment: Why would the footer move? Your menu is positioned absolutely so it doesn't affect any other elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's why I'm asking, to find out why. My CSS knowledge is lacking, I'm not a designer by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: So that's your answer. If you want the dropdown to expand the main element (which I doubt frankly...it would be an odd thing to do) then you need to remove the absolute positioning. https://jsfiddle.net/fmoctax3/

Comment: @Paulie_D Gotcha, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I can suggest you to make the scrollable dropdown, as it's not the right UI if you have a very big dropdown.

Just add the below css,

```
.scroll{
  max-height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width:150px;
}
```

And apply the 'scroll' css to the div 'menu'

```
 <div class="menu scroll">
```